Low AUC value for XGBoost binary classification model
I am using XGBoost to construct a binary classification model to identify individuals with a diagnosis based on things like weight, average steps per day, age, etc. My model is quite small (only 200 cases), and unbalanced (4:1 negative to positive ratio). I've constructed an XGBoost model, but I notice that through tuning, I am only achieving test AUC results < .5, with some models providing test AUC values of .2-.3. The training AUC values vary from .3-.6. I have attempted to use SMOTE, but it hasn't improved the classification accuracy much. The labels are not being switched, and there is no coding error. I am using gamma, lambda, and positive weight scaling parameters to reduce the chance of overfitting. However, nothing seems to be working to improve the AUC of the model above .5.
Conceptually, I'm not quite sure I understand how a binary classification model can be capable of achieving perfectly incorrect guesses but not capable of achieving perfectly correct guesses. If the model can be almost entirely inaccurate  in its discrimination(AUC < .2), couldn't it be capable of a good result (AUC > .8) as well?

Regarding "unbalanced" data and SMOTE, you may find this thread interesting.

From what is described, it appears that it is likele that there are not enough data available to train a booster adequately. In general, tree-based learners because of their non-parametric nature (i.e. they do fewer assumptions about the nature of the data) require more data than parametric learners (e.g. a ridge regression classifier), van der Ploeg et al. (2014) Modern modelling techniques are data hungry: a simulation study for predicting dichotomous endpoints is very good first read on the matter.
(Assuming no coding errors) I would suggest two immediate points:

Start with some much simpler classifiers (e.g. a Naive Bayes and ridge regression classifier) and establish what are some baselines in terms of performance.
A sample of ~200 instances is generally quite small, to justify having a separate test set. Employ a resampling technique (e.g. repeated CV) in order to get some more reliable performance estimates.

I would also make two smaller suggestions:

Don't start with SMOTE. It is not catastrophic, but it is definitely not a panacea when having smaller and/or imbalanced samples. 20-80 spit is not severely imbalanced for most cases, the main issue is here the small sample size.
Investigate the shape of the models' learning curves. That should be informative both in terms of how much a model in question gets better with more data, but also how efficient it is.

Finally, a bit of commentary the side-question regarding: "If the model can be almost entirely inaccurate in its discrimination(AUC < .2), couldn't it be capable of a good result (AUC > .8) as well?"
This is a slightly simplistic way of judging model perfomance. Yes, if we had some AUC-ROC values close to 0.40-0.60 with a large enough sample, then this assertion could be likely true. It would suggest that the model detects some weak structure and recalibrating our label assignment process could give us some benefits. However, in this case, given the small sample size and the large performance difference between test and training set, it is more likely that the model suffers from overfitting and inability to generalise to the test. When a model performs this inconsistently, it is more often due to overfitting to noise in the training sample rather than capturing meaningful structure. Better results will likely come from rethinking the model design and/or feature engineering rather than attempting to adjust labels.
